# firefox has blocked content that isn't secure

Tags: firefox

I am running a site. Some of its pages are not working in Firefox, but work perfect in Chrome. In Firefox it shows me a gray shield next to the URL and when I click on that shield and manually click on *disable protection on this page* then my page works fine. So now the problem is that there are many users on my site, and some of them don't know how to do it so I want to handle it on my site so its users don't need to do that.

How can I do it? I Googled and found a setting of Firefox in `about:config` named `security.mixed_content.block_active_content`. If we set it to false then it works. So is there a way to do it programmatically or other way so that users just view that page without seeing that shield?

Comment: For what it's worth, you are not alone - there are a number of large sites out there that are nearly unusable in Firefox now because of this.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, content that is blocked by default by Firefox now is http content that is accessed from an https page. Common types of content that fall foul of this are external stylesheets and images.

As far as I am aware the way to prevent the problem on your site is to make sure that if a page is served by https, any and all other files that it references are also served by https.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi Friends,**

> The reason you see this error in Mozilla Firefox is because your
>   website is a Mixed Box that is, your website has many internal links
>   which are not SSL protected.
>
> In order to avoid this error from showing up in Mozilla Firefox you
>   will have to make sure all the internal links on your website are SSL
>   protected.

So, Use **https://** in your page not **http://**

**I hope I was clear enough in answering your query.**

Answer (score 0):

`firefox has blocked content that isn't secure` means there are some contents on your website are not secure. 
I had same issue as my fonts were downloading with http://google.apis.something instead of https

Then I change to **//google.apis.something** and problem get solved.

To know what is not secure in you website use [this link](https://www.whynopadlock.com/)